# Matching key found, but still require password [preauth]

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh

I use SSH to connect to a machine. There is no password access, only an existing SSH key which works.

I need to create a new key (production.key, production.key.pub) which I did like this, without choosing a passphrase:

```
cd /home
sudo ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I then copied the public key to the machine like this:

```
cat /home/production.key.pub | ssh -i /home/old_key user@<IP> "cat >> /root/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I then tried to log in like this:

```
ssh -i /home/production.key user@<IP>
```

But I still get a password prompt. So I tried again with sshd in debug mode, and got this output:

```
debug1: matching key found: file /root/.ssh/authorized_keys, line 2 RSA XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Postponed publickey for root from XX.XX.XX.XX port 60407 ssh2 [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user root service ssh-connection method password [preauth]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why do I still get a password prompt when it says 'matching key found'? How do I fix this?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I fixed this by changing the permissions on the private key from 600 to 644:

```
 sudo chmod 644 /home/production.key
```

Comment: 644 throws an error for bad permissions for key file. 600 is correct, though I still face the original issue above.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message from sshd and figured out the private key file was actually missing on the client side. Only the public key was there.